# Regex Assistance - checkout through to confirmation

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Good afternoon all,

I am trying to work out some RegEx for tracking both the checkout page and the thank you page for a client.

Info: 
URL STRUCTURE (checkout vs thank you):
/3396517/checkouts/56605845b31b269b0853e7f78b700e7b

/3396517/checkouts/27c9d1d400c3d740be608de497ac704e/thank_you

Basically we need to be able to differentiate these areas, so they dont overlap. The number before the checkouts remains the same.

checkout - /3396517/checkouts/*

thankyou - ^/thank_you$

Will this work? If not, could someone with some advanced RegEx knowledge help me out please? The reason for this is to trigger a different event, for both the going to checkout then the thank you page, they need to be different from each other. Whether that be making the checkout not trigger for anything with thank you etc.

Thanks,

Jake.

Comment: Is it for GA? For *checkout*, you may use `/3396517/checkouts/` and for *thank you*, you may use `/thank_you$` (if this is the last subpart in the URL).

Comment: Hi, its not for GA, it is for another analytics tool that has full Regex functionality.

Comment: Does it require a full string match, or does it allow partial matches?

Comment: It allows for partial matches yes

Comment: Is this a checkout page or a thank you page `/3396517/checkouts/27c9d1d400c3d740be608de497ac704e/thank_you` ?

Comment: A single regex will get both types: if `^/3396517/checkouts(?=/).*?(/thank_yo‌​u)?/?$` then if group 1 then _thankspage_ else _checkout_ page.

Comment: Hi Sln, thats a great solution! Only problem is here we need to set up both of the stages as domain paths, where the regex will be used individually to identify both stages. Any other solution here?

Comment: @JakeStevens - Either I don't understand or you don't. If both url types contain common strings, the difference is the un-common part. In this case it's _thank you_ at the end. A single match of `^/3396517/checkouts(?=/).*?(/thank_yo‌​u)?/?$` tells you that it is a checkout and if or if not a thank you as well. No need to beat a dead horse. If they contain common string, you only need a single regex to get info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system allows for partial matches ad you are interested in matching 2 types of strings: 1) containing `/3396517/checkouts/` substring, and 2) those ending with `/thank_you`.

The first type of strings does not need a regex, and if you just can tell your system to match the string that contains `/3396517/checkouts/` it will be enough. At any rate, `/3396517/checkouts/` is already a valid string pattern, you do not even need to change anything in it.

To match `/thank_you` at the end of the URL, you may use `/thank_you$` or, if there can be a trailing `/` at the end, add an optional `/` using `/thank_you/?$`. `/?` matches 1 or 0 consecutive occurrences of `/` and `$` matches the end of string.

When you want to test regex online, escape `/` char as it is often used as a regex delimiter. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7y0EBX/1).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! I will take a look into this then let you know the outcome,.

Comment: @JakeStevens Whenver you need more help with this task, please feel free to drop a comment here.

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to let you know.